# How can I rewrite my ansible playbook so I can pass multiple values to a variable instead of duplicating the code each time?

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

**How do I supply multiple values to the variable `delete_signer_cert_cert_id`** in the following playbook and instead of duplicating the code multiple times?

```yaml
- name: Delete expired signer certs
  hosts: all
  ignore_errors: true
  connection: local
  roles:
   - role: delete_signer_cert
     delete_signer_cert_kdb_id : "pdsrv"
     delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "ATTWiFiIssuingTest"

   - role: delete_signer_cert
     delete_signer_cert_kdb_id : "pdsrv"
     delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority"

   - role: delete_signer_cert
     delete_signer_cert_kdb_id : "pdsrv"
     delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)"

   - role: delete_signer_cert
     delete_signer_cert_kdb_id : "pdsrv"
     delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "Entrust.net Client Certification Authority"
```

I tried something like this but in vain

```yaml
---
- name: Delete expired signer certs
  hosts: all
  ignore_errors: true
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - expiredsamlcerts.yml
  roles:
    - role: delete_signer_cert
     delete_signer_cert_kdb_id : "samlkeys"
     delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "{{ item.my_list }}"
     loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

The file I supplied looks like this `vi ~/expiredsamlcerts.yml`

```yaml
my_list:
  - saml_signer_14821_storm3ft_mc
  - saml_signer_14821_storm3ft_cm
  - saml_signer_14821_storm3ft_ds
```

**Error**

> {"msg": "The conditional check 'delete_signer_cert_kdb_id is defined and delete_signer_cert_cert_id is defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (delete_signer_cert_kdb_id is defined and delete_signer_cert_cert_id is defined): {{ item.my_list }}: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/opt/app/ipa/roles/ipa_galaxy_roles/delete_signer_cert/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Delete signer certificate\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: It is not clear how the items of `my_list` are related to the role's variables `*_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [*include_role*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-module-load-and-execute-a-role). For example, given the role for testing

```yaml
shell> cat roles/delete_signer_cert/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: |
      delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: {{ delete_signer_cert_kdb_id }}
      delete_signer_cert_cert_id: {{ delete_signer_cert_cert_id }}
```

The play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ids:
      - {kdb: pdsrv, cert: "ATTWiFiIssuingTest"}
      - {kdb: pdsrv, cert: "Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority"}
      - {kdb: pdsrv, cert: "Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)"}
      - {kdb: pdsrv, cert: "Entrust.net Client Certification Authority"}

  tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: delete_signer_cert
      loop: "{{ ids }}"
      vars:
        delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: "{{ item.kdb }}"
        delete_signer_cert_cert_id: "{{ item.cert }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [include_role : delete_signer_cert] ******************************************************

TASK [delete_signer_cert : debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: pdsrv
    delete_signer_cert_cert_id: ATTWiFiIssuingTest

TASK [delete_signer_cert : debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: pdsrv
    delete_signer_cert_cert_id: Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority

TASK [delete_signer_cert : debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: pdsrv
    delete_signer_cert_cert_id: Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)

TASK [delete_signer_cert : debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    delete_signer_cert_kdb_id: pdsrv
    delete_signer_cert_cert_id: Entrust.net Client Certification Authority

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```